# Git: Automatic Staging

Tags: git, latex

Is there a way to always stage a certain file for commit, or maybe better, have it be ignored by git status listing, but still be updated in the repo. I have a repository for a tex project, and there are a number of pdf files that I want in my repo, but knowing that they are different (which can often be as little of a difference as a forced rerun rather than any changes) is useless to me, and bogs up the status.

An example is, when I modify a section of text in a given location, which is indicated by the tex subfile name, it reminds me what I was working on; but this can be often coupled to 2 or 3 different pdf files that also changed due to this, and so my one small change has 3 or 4 files listed as modified, making it harder to distinguish what, and how much was changed.

I did try to add a manual `git add` command into my latex compilation, but this is a bit funky, and a bit too detached for my liking.

Comment: Maybe I am not getting this right. the PDFs are coming out of "building" the latex files? Are they included in version control?

Comment: Sounds like you should add `*.pdf` to `.gitignore`. If these files are made out of your `*.tex` sources, there is no reason to store them in Git.

Comment: I want them in git so that I have access to them on GitHub if I push there (so that I can remotely access the compiled documen. Additionally, when I checkout an old version of the project, sometimes this is to check a previous calculation, which will be in the pdf, rather than having to compile the latex after I checkout again)